# How to add a cell with an inline string value to a Spreadsheet using the Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

When using the Open XML SDK to add cells with non-numeric text to a worksheet, the [officially documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-text-into-a-cell-in-a-spreadsheet) method is to use the shared string table. While I recognize the performance and storage efficiency benefits of this approach in the general use case, when creating spreadsheets programmatically, this is a lot of work to do something seemingly simple: The programmer is required to create the shared string table, add entries and maintain entries (including checking if a string already exists in the table), potentially negating the supposed benefits.

The alternative is to use inline string markup, which is mentioned in the documentation, but no example is given. I couldn't find any examples via [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20open%20xml%20sdk%20spreadsheets%20inline%20string%20cell%20value%20example) either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to create a cell with an inline string value programmatically using the C# OpenXML SDK:

```cs
var inlineString = new InlineString { Text = new Text("Foobar") };
cellWithInlineStr = new Cell(inlineString) { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
```